# Do self-inflating sleeping pads have to be kept dry during trips?

Tags: rain, sleeping-pads

**Context:** I'm planning to take my self-inflating sleeping pad on a bike trip this year. The bike doesn't have any mounting points for a rack, so space is somewhat limited. Currently, my plan is to simply strap the pad to the handlebars in the manufacturer-provided stuff sack.

**Question:** Do self-inflating pads need to be protected from rain? Will water from the outside do any damage? I'm wondering whether I should get a dry bag or whether the (not fully waterproof) stuff sack is enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not exactly, if your sleeping pad gets wet and you lay your sleeping bag on top of it then your sleeping bag will get wet and that's not a good thing.

Otherwise, your sleeping pad is **preventing air from getting out, and that means its capable of keeping water out.**

On the other hand blowing into it will introduce moisture which can be a problem in cold conditions.

> Winter use: If freezing
>   conditions will be encountered daily for several weeks, avoid breath inflation. Moisture from breath may accumulate and freeze inside the mattress. Under extremely cold
>   conditions, the mattress may be slow to self-inflate.

[Source](http://www.wou.edu/campusrec/files/2015/06/Self-Inflate-Brochure.pdf)